# Identifying Parts of speech

Tags: clauses, parsing, parts-of-speech

I'm very confused about this sentence. Can anyone explain it to me in detail?

> I don't want to know how you did it.

Comment: What is the sentence? Do you mean "I don't want to know how you did it" is the sentence that confused you?

Comment: yes.not the sentence meaning but i am confused with parts of speech of this sentence@DamkerngT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Grammar**

The Subject of the sentence is the pronoun "*I*". The Predicate is:

- don't want to know how you did it.

The Head of the verb phrase is the word *don't*, which is  contraction of the dummy auxiliary verb *do* and the negative particle *not*. This takes as its Complement the verb phrase:

- want to know how you do it.

The Head of this verb phrase is the verb *want*. The word *want* takes as its Complement the infinitival clause:

- to know how you did it.

The Head of his phrase, depending on your grammar, is probably the verb *know* (some writers would argue the Head is the word *to*). The word *to* in this case is a subordinator which marks *know how you did it* as subordinate. The verb *know* takes as its Complement the interrogative finite clause:

- how you did it.

The Subject of this clause is the pronoun *you*. The Head of the clause is the verb *did*. The Direct Object is the pronoun *it*. The clause has an Adjunct, the interrogative adverb *how*, which has been fronted to the beginning of the clause.

The verb *want* is a control verb. This means that if there is no expressed Subject of the following infinitive clause, we understand the Subject of *want* to be the Subject of the following infinitive. So the sentence can be interpreted like this:

- I don't want [ (me) to know how you did it ].

**Meaning**

Suppose the listener has done something. Maybe they stole some jewels from a museum and nobody caught them. To do something like this, the listener would need to use some kind of plan or method. This is what is expressed by:

- how you did it.

The word *how* refers to the method used. The speaker is telling the listener "*I do not want to know the method!*". Of course we don't know what the listener actually did. It might be something quite boring.

Answer (score 1):

In place of the contraction "don't", I'll use the expansion "do not".

I -- first-person singular subjective pronoun; subject of "do want"
 do -- auxiliary; part of the verb "do want"
 not -- adverb, modifies "do want"
 want -- verb, transitive, present tense, indefinite aspect, active voice, indicative mode
 to know -- infinitive; begins the phrase that is the direct object of "do want"
 how -- subordinating conjunction; begins the clause that is the direct object of "to know"
 you -- second-person subjective pronoun; subject of "did"
 did -- verb, transitive, past tense, indefinite aspect, active voice, indicative mode
 it -- third-person neuter singular objective pronoun; direct object of "did"

Another way to label the word "how" is as a conjunctive adverb.

Comment: *"want -- verb, transitive, present tense, indefinite aspect, active voice, indicative mode"* <== Er, is "want" really in present tense?

Comment: You could sensibly argue that "do" marks the tense and "want" has no tense at all.  I often do.  However, the listed properties (including present tense) belong to the complete verb, and for that reason listing them with the main verb makes sense.